# Email with href link always going to spam

Tags: email, html-email, spam, email-spam

We have a verification email where we are sending a link to verify, but this mail is always going to spam on Gmail. If i remove the link then it goes to inbox.
the `VERIFY_EMAIL_LINK` is replaced by the verification link. I also tried using other urls too, even with wikipedia it's going to spam.

" +
                "اضغط هنا لتأكيد بريدك الإلكتروني" +
                "

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue , i was using `link` like this and thus it was going to spam. The moment i removed it, it worked